# NetBeans Janitor scan reports old versions

Tags: netbeans

I'm running NetBeans 12.6 on Wndows 10 (although this happened on previous versions).  When I startup, after a pause, I get Notifications, saying "NetBeans 8.1 was last used 1,959 days ago".

If I click on it it offers to "Remove unused data and cache directories of NetBeans 8.1. Free up 154 MB of disk space."

If I say yes... nothing happens.   And next time I run Janitor scan (from Tools>Options>Janitor, or on startup) the message is still there.

%APPDATA%..\Local\NetBeans\Cache does not contain an 8.1 directory, so it's not the cache.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to make this work?  and where are the 154MB of files it's referring to?

Thanks

Comment: I've also got those prompts, but when I click the _"Remove unused..."_ message and reply **Yes** in the _Confirm Cleanup_ window I very briefly see a message flash on the bottom of the screen in the Status Bar, and the prompt is gone when I restart, indicating that Janitor worked. Something to try: [1] Run Janitor manually, then go to **Window > IDE Tools > Notifications** to verify that you see the _"Remove unused..."_ message(s). If so, click one to instigate a clean up, checking for output in the Status Bar, then go to the Netbeans log (**View > IDE Log**) to see if there are any errors.

Comment: No errors are shown at View -> IDE Log in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Janitor notification. Except in my case I did find the cached folder it was referring to.

Kept getting the message to clean up xGB of old cache. Responded "Yes" and Janitor silently failed to clean up the old cache. Got annoyed, looked in the IDE log found the line

Cache Directory         = "...."

Went to the cached directory, one level up, found and manually deleted the old cache folder. Problem solved.